# How to use jQuery toggleClass to optimize code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code that validates input fields for empty values.
It works, but I realized with jQuery toggleClass, I might be able to improve upon it or optimize it.
But I  can't figure a way out.
 Any help will be appreciated.

```js
 $(function() {

   $('.cont').on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     $('.cont input').filter(function() {

       return !this.value.trim();

     }).addClass('highlight');

   });

   //remove red borders if field contains input
   $('.cont').find('input').blur(function(event) {
     if ($(this).val() && $(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
       $(this).removeClass('highlight');
     }
   });
 })
```

```css
.highlight {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the class on successful validation?

Comment: @Dave Newton can you please demonstrate how?

Comment: `if ($(this).val()) $(this.removeClass('highlight');`

Comment: Or you could just use a change handler that adds or removes based on current value. My point was that toggling isn't useful without keeping track of the previous state, and since you have to examine the value to get the *current* state you should just use that.

Comment: I was thinking I could refactor the code using the toggleClass so that the second part that does the if checks will be removed entirely. I tried but I keep getting unexpected results.

Comment: what is the "unexpected result" that you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[toggleClass(class)](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) takes a lesser-known second optional boolean argument 'state', so can also be used to remove the class without having to keep track of state...

I'd recommend calculating the state of whether it is valid or not and then passing that to toggleState() so that it will also clear the red border when valid without additional code.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.cont').on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.cont input').each(function(it) {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', !(this).value.trim());
    });

  });
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow! that's awesome. So I just needed to iterate over the input elements.  I couldn't figure this out. Thanks!